# LibGDX In-App purchases and Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases to my project which is using gradle in Android Studio.

My problem is, is that I've not idea how to include the Android-sdk in the project.

For example, if I try to create something simple like the IabHelper object it cannot even be resolved (which makes me think that the library isn't working).

Does anyone have any experience in this? I've been trying to resolve this all day in my personal time on my day off, very frustrating.

My current gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
        classpath 'com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'MyAppName'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.1'
        //roboVMVersion = '0.0.13'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0-beta-01'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {

    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"

        //compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:1.4.0"

        compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.4.0'
        compile 'net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.4.0' // Box2D module
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

** UPDATE **

Unfortunately I couldn't resolve this after a whole week of effort, I even reformatted my MAC and redownloaded everything, didn't work. Gradle...

Anyhow, I resolved by using an excellent third party library that just require one line of code:

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you need at least this in your `project(":android")`

```
android {
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
compileSdkVersion 19
}
```

Comment: I can see that LibGDX 1.4.1 supports Android build tools version 20. Check which version you are using and adjust the buildToolsVersion accordingly. Have you installed the latest Android build tools? You need to install them for the gradle script to run.

Comment: I using version 1.5, I'll try this tonight. Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: This doesn't help. Gradle still can't find the files.

Answer (score 0):

`IabHelper` class located in `com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util` package. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) you should copy `utils` directory with `IabHelper` class from sample *TrivialDrive* app to your project.

> To add the In-app Billing Version 3 library to your existing In-app Billing project:
>
> 1. Copy the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file to your Android project.
>
>    - In Android Studio: Create a directory named `aidl` under `src/main`, add a new package > `com.android.vending.billing` in this directory, and import the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into this package.
>    - In Eclipse: Import the IInAppBillingService.aidl file into your /src directory.
>    - In other dev environments: Create the following directory `/src/com/android/vending/billing` and copy the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into this directory.
> 2. Build your application. You should see a generated file named `IInAppBillingService.java` in the /gen directory of your project.
> 3. Add the helper classes from the `/util` directory of the `TrivialDrive` sample to your project. Remember to change the package name declarations in those files accordingly so that your project compiles correctly.
>
> Your project should now contain the In-app Billing Version 3 library.

After this steps you will be able to create `IabHelper` object in your code.

Comment: No luck, I can't even compile the Google Play services (Latest version +)